# Why is the footer not at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a site I am working on. I want to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page.
So I followed a simple guide which basically did this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: $footer-height + $footer-margin-top;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: $footer-height;
}
```

This seemed to work at the start. Then I got to a stage where the content was more than the view port height and that is when things stopped working.

If you look at [this](http://piiick-widget.azurewebsites.net/#/) you can see that the footer is at the bottom of the page.

But if you look at [this](http://piiick-widget.azurewebsites.net/#/?matches=true), the footer is at the bottom of the viewport.
I know this is a simple fix, but I can't figure it out.
Can someone give me a hand please.

Comment: Change `position:absolute` for `.footer` to `position: fixed`

Comment: https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx

Take a look at the link that would be excatly what you want!

Comment: Sanket, that is the exact tutorial I followed, but it didn't work on my site for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your footer to stick at the bottom of the page unless the content on `body` is large enough that it appears after you scroll?

If so, you should set `height: auto;` on your body tag, so if it's more than `100%` set on your `min-height` rule, it's taking into consideration and pushes the footer towards the bottom.

Let me know if that's your intended behaviour.

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what i wanted. I knew it would be simple :)

Comment: Doesn't quite work. If the html is set to auto, then when the content is larger than the view area it does put the footer at the bottom. If the content is less than the view area then it just sits at the bottom of the content (I need it at the bottom of the view area)

Comment: Are you talking about footer being on the bottom of the viewport? Clyde already answered it. YOu need .footer fixed positioning.

Comment: Not on the `html`, on your `body` tag you should have. `min-height: 100%`, `height: auto` and it will give you the behaviour you want (just tried it on your site adding and removing content). If not if you could provide a minimum coplete and verifiable example I can continue helping. You accepted Clyde's answer however, is your issue solved?

Comment: I misread yours. I have now done as you have specified and you are right. It works exactly as I have requested, so I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`position:absolute` for `.footer` to `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer {
    position: static;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: $footer-height;
}
```